# Adding Google map in Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, loading

I am using ionic framework. In which I have templates of html in Script tag. I am unable to load google map in the template through javascript.

```
<script id="templates/facts.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Facts">
        <ion-content padding="true">
            <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
</script>
```

in my main javascript file i was loading map like this.

```
function initialize() {
   var mapProp = {
   center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
   zoom:5,
   mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

i have also try loading map using in-line script tag but that too isn't working for me

Comment: In that code you're not loading the Maps API at all. If you want to load the API asynchronously, follow [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async). If you want to load it with a `<script>` tag, follow [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple). Post a *complete* test page (not just excerpts) if it still doesn't work. Also, do you know how to use the JavaScript debugger?  Here is an [introduction to the Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

Comment: I have tried all these links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way you are using google maps in your application is not recommended. It would be very difficult for you to work this way. Since ionic is a single page application, google map would be loaded whether you are showing google map or not.

Best way is to use [angular-google-maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/use).

[From quickstart:](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/use)

1. In root of your page execute `bower install angular-google-maps`
2. Load dependencies
3. load google map script

Finally inject the directive:

```
angular.module('myApplicationModule', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps']).config(
    ['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider', function(GoogleMapApiProviders) {
        GoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
            china: true
        });
    }]
);
```

Good luck!